# ExpandableListAdapter in a DialogPreference

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Im trying to add an ExpandableListAdapter to a DialogPrefence.

My layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/channels_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/channelsProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbChannelsProgress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how I did it with a ListView

```
HiddenChannelsListAdapter adapter = new HiddenChannelsListAdapter(ctx, tree, subscribed_channelsList);
ListView lv = (ListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

How must I do it with a ExpandableListAdapter?

```
ExampleReallySimpleExpandableListAdapter adapter = new ExampleReallySimpleExpandableListAdapter(ctx, groupData, childData);
AbsListView lv = (AbsListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This results in:

```
03-25 14:24:23.780: E/AndroidRuntime(22187): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 14:24:23.780: E/AndroidRuntime(22187): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tvrplayer.ExampleReallySimpleExpandableListAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.ListAdapter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setAdapter(ExpandableListAdapter)` from `ExpandableListView`, not the generic `setAdapter(ListAdapter)` from `AbsListView`.

That is, change

```
AbsListView lv = (AbsListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

to

```
ExpandableListView lv = (ExpandableListView) vw.findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: Do you know If one can make them expanded by default?

Comment: @Harry, what do you mean? Calling `expandGroup()` on groups you want to be expanded by default?